# Add padding between Location input and error message

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, preferences

https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current

> [image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is not correctly styled according to the [Stack Design System](https://stackoverflow.design/product/components/inputs/#validation-examples). Maybe a bug is a better tag?

Comment: I'll refrain from comments that this location thing now all of sudden assumes we need to be somewhere on earth ...